# ajax response run javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want run same js code after ajax response.

js code is

```
<script>
var wid = 2670, gid = 8412;
var rpHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
var tt = "t_reklamporttakip_Kozmetik_1x1_Uye_Takip";
var ciid = 4541454;
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + rpHost + "ad.reklamport.com/scripts/rpn.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + rpHost + "ad.reklamport.com/rpgetad.ashx?tt=" + tt + "&ciid=" + ciid + "&rnd=" + Math.random() % 99999999 + "' %3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

how to i run this code some as

```
jQuery.get('url', function(response){
    // i want run here!
});
```

Any suggestions from anyone

Comment: You simply want to run the code within the `<script>` tags within the success call back on the `get()` function ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are fetching JavaScript from the server,use [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)